# How to change the email address of a user in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC4 App. I actually want to be able to change the email address of a user.

ModifyEmail.cshtml

```html
@model Project.Models.ModifyEmailModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Manage", "Account")) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Change Email Address</legend>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OldEmailAddress)
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.OldEmailAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OldEmailAddress)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewEmailAddress)
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.NewEmailAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewEmailAddress)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmEmailAddress)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmEmailAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmEmailAddress)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Changer l'addresse email" />
</fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

AccountModels.cs

```
    namespace Project.Models
{
    public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }

    }


    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
    }


    public class ModifyEmailModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "l'addresse email actuelle est requise")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Addresse email actuelle")]
        public string OldEmailAddress { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "la nouvelle addresse email est requise")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Nouvelle addresse email")]
        public string NewEmailAddress { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirmer la nouvelle addresse mail")]
        [Compare("NewEmailAddress", ErrorMessage = "Le nouvelle addresse email et la confirmation de l'addresse email ne correspondent pas.")]
        public string ConfirmEmailAddress { get; set; }
    }




}
```

I can't figure out how to implement the action in the AccountController.cs, Please help!

Comment: what do you have in your account controller right now?

Comment: sorry. but your questions is very unclear. What do u want to do? and what have u tried yet??

Comment: I want to create an action ModifyEmail to be able to enter the old/new and confirm email and save it into the DB. It should be similar to managing the password but I can't figure out how to implement it

Comment: Well, I have a lot of actions. I want to add this feature for the user to be able to manage his/her email address

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your description, you want an action method to modify the email address. So, you can try the following,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Manage(ModifyEmailModel data)
{
    if(data.NewEmailAddress == data.ConfirmEmailAddress)
    {
        // db is your context instance
        var u = db.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.EmailId == OldEmailAddress).SingleOrDefault();
        u.EmailID = data.NewEmailAddress;
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
    else
        string error = "Email ID's don't match";
    return View();
}
```

To display email in your view in you GET method, i.e. the method which is loading the view, put the following,

```
public ActionResult Manage()
{
    // at this point you must have the username for your currently logged in user
    var u = db.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.UserName == UserName).SingleOrDefault();
    return View(u);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually have a few other issues I want to display the current email address  so in the view i put:  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OldEmailAddress)
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.OldEmailAddress) but it's not displaying the email address

Comment: is it loading from controller??

Comment: What do you mean? I don't get it, sorry

Comment: when you are loading the view, Does the OldEmailAddress property has any data??

Comment: No, but I want to link it to the EmailId in the db

Comment: Thank you for the update. I was trying to figure out how while separating the get and post actions

Comment: Post methods have [HttpPost] attribute on start of method.. see my update.. I think you need to see some tutorials on MVC before starting anything

Comment: So in my GET action, I did this  but it's not showing the current email. Other than that, please advise me on some tutorials for MVC.            public ActionResult ModifyEmail(String UserName)
        {
            UserProfile user = db.UserProfiles.Find(UserName);
            var u = db.UserProfiles.Where(x => x.UserName == UserName).SingleOrDefault();
            return View(u);
        }

Comment: go and take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/866143/Learn-MVC-Project-in-days-Day
, http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started
,

Answer (score 0):

The default identity account controller uses the Manage action to update or create a password right? If you want to retain this, I would suggest you create another GET action to something like ManageEmail where you can return the view above that you just created from a link or button click under the original Manage page. Then create a POST action ManageEmail to do the change email/ update async with the new email.

Inside Manage.cshtml, you can call a different get method inside it using Html.Action.

```
@Html.Partial("_ChangePassword") // change password partial here
@Html.Action("ManageEmail") // this will call the partial view page with your custom model
```

Inside your AccountController.cs add these 2 methods:

```
//GET ManageEmail
public ActionResult ManageEmail()
{
   var model = new ModifyEmailModel()
    {
     OldEmailAddress = UserManager.GetEmail(User.Identity.GetUserId()) // this will load the current email for your view
    };
   return View("_ManageEmail",model); // _ManageEmail is your partial view name
```

}

```
//POST ManageEmail
[HttpPost()]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public async Task<ActionResult> ManageEmail(ModifyEmailModel data)
{
  //some validation here like if email is valid or not existing in the database to avoid duplicate
  var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
  await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
  return RedirectToAction("Manage");
}
```

Then just edit your partial view to target the ManageEmail POST action.

Comment: Well, What I'm doing actually is having ModifyEmail.cshtml as a partial view called in Manage.cshtml. So I have two partial views there : ModifyEmail.cshtml and _ ChangePasswordPartial. I'm still having some issues concerning using two models in one view I used tuple but when I submit I always get an error

Comment: @xxxx if that's the case, that is fine but I suggest you separate the get method for the two different jobs. You can load a partial view by calling a get method using Html.Action. Let me update my answer I will show you.

Comment: @xxxx see my updated answer, should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the update. That helps a lot! and I can see how the structure should be. I will test it now

Comment: @xxxx Glad it helped. Good luck! ~

Comment: What  does UserManager stands for?

Comment: @xxxx UserManager is the built in repository that holds methods you can use to perform different actions for the User class such as UpdateAsync, GetByIdAsync. I suggest you need more about aspnet identity here. http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: Thanks for the link. When I type the code you've given me,  UserManager is underlined in red saying it does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @xxxx It might be called differently like ApplicationUserManager depending on the version of MVC you are using. You can easily find what visual studio generated for you by looking at the HttpPost Manage method in your AccountController.cs, what does it use to change the password of the user.

Comment: I'm actually developing in ASP.NET MVC4.  In the Manage POST,  they are using WebSecurity :   changePasswordSucceeded = WebSecurity.ChangePassword(User.Identity.Name, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);

Comment: It is handled on MVC5 but not in MVC4